# How can I apply webfonts to an email Header?

Tags: html, webfonts

I use a pretty standard SaaS Email campaign manager to deliver emails for my client.

The issue I come up against is my client uses speciality typefaces so when designing the layouts for these emails I typically save all text as an image.

Instead I would like to find a way to use the webfont version of the typefaces so they render as text for SEO purposes.

I tried using typekit, but typekit only works for a specific domain. Are there alternatives that don't requiring expert-level programming?

Comment: I'm confused - SEO purposes but in Email? That doesn't make any sense. And what have you tried because @import should work, as well as anything else in html email at least (which means inconsistently at best).

Comment: Yes, SEO and Email don't make sense together.

Answer (score 0):

Using web fonts for an email is kind of tricky. If you want to be consistent then you will be better off sticking with an image. Not all email clients will use web fonts.

[image: web font for email client]

This is taken from [campaignmonitor.com: Web font support in email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/webfonts/). They have a pretty extensive guide on web type.

So if you "need" the font to show for branding reasons then stick to the image export.

If this is for an aesthetic purpose then use the web font and accept that it will not render correctly for all email clients. <strike>Just make sure to pick a fallback font that is accepted for all email clients</strike>.

> No need to pick a 'fallback'. All email clients already have that (the
>   user's default font preference). –  DA01

Comment: No need to pick a 'fallback'. All email clients already have that (the user's default font preference).

Comment: You might still want to pick a fallback that is closer to the intended font than the system default.